# Facebook sdk .net c# error message

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm trying to connect to facebook using the Facebook SDK in c# to get user details.

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();
client.AppId = appId;
dynamic me = client.Get("me");
```

The error message I am receiving in line 3 is:

> A first chance exception of type 'Facebook.FacebookOAuthException' occurred in Facebook.dll

Does anyone know what I did wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the client with an access token (from the .net sdk):

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
```

There are various different types of access token, have a look at the facebook dev page for this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. I'm not sure how to get the user access token:
 I have logged the user in
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.client_id = appId;
            parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
            parameters.response_type = "token";
            parameters.display = "popup";

            var login = client.GetLoginUrl(parameters);

but dont know how to continue

Comment: When you say you logged the user in, what exactly do you mean?  For example I would normally go request an access **code** then exchange it for an access toke with something like:

_dynamic result = fbClient.Post("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = "ClientId",
                client_secret = "app secret",
                redirect_uri = redirectUrl,
                code = theCode
            });_